# How to burn .raw file on USB?

Tags: 14.04, burning, usb-creator

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to burn `.raw` file, its installation for OS X so it should be bootable. I need to burn it to my USB. How to do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `dd` for this.

First list your devices with

```
lsblk
```

and find the USB device that you want to write to (for example, `/dev/sdb`, *this might be different for you*).

Unmount the device by:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
```

Then write your file to USB by:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/file/downloaded of=/dev/sdb
```

**Make sure you select the correct drive in `of=`**

Comment: I got problem. When I write:                                   dd if=/home/mark/Downloads of=/dev/sdc1                                                                   I get this error dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdc1’: Permission denied

Comment: @MarkShou you need `sudo dd …`.

Comment: @Mark Shou Since you are a new user, If this post helped you, you can mark this as the answer to your question. :)

Comment: Does this work for ISO files as well, right?

Comment: I prepared raw file using qemu/kvm (booting with UEFI, then installed Ubuntu 19.04, added few programs and configured it). Then I wrote that image to the USB thumb using above method. After configuring laptop to boot in UEFI mode it does not recognize thumb stick as a bootable medium. What I could do to fix it? I additionally tried to read that image in GParted and it does not recognize it as a properly formed drive with partitions and files systems.